# Autofill password on multiple pages of one site

Tags: google-chrome, auto-form-fill

I use a specific site for work, which has multiple case files. I have to enter my username and password after entering information on 2 separate pages of that site. Google Chrome was auto-filling both pages but now has stopped working on one page. How do I get it to autofill on both pages? I tried adding the URL for the second page, but I get an error that says I already have a username and password saved for that site.

Comment: Would using a different password manager be an acceptable solution? You could export your passwords into bitwarden and enjoy a by default more secure password manager with many more functions.

Comment: I tried using bitwarden and it doesn't autofill either, but it doesn't fill on either page, only the main log in.

Comment: Check with firefox, if it also happens there, contact your company IT support.

Comment: It's somewhat trivial to prevent password managers from autofilling forms.  Are you sure the behavior you describe isn't intentional by the website owner?

Comment: I questioned that and was told that it isn't on their end. It was working fine for the past year and just stopped about 3 weeks ago.